# subprocess-exited-with-error when installing Python libraries in venv

Tags: python, windows, pip, virtualenv

I'm having trouble installing Python dependencies in a virtual environment. I am on a Windows 11 laptop and have multiple version of Python installed (3.10 & 3.11). I am using git bash from a VS Code terminal and got the following output. I'm not sure what's causing this issue. Also, unrelated but when not using a venv and trying to run a file with libraries after installing them with pip or pip3 I get an error saying that the libraries are unknown.

I haven't used Python since installing mingw which seems to be a part of the issue.

How can I fix this?

```
my_pc  MINGW64 ~/OneDrive/Documents/Trading/interviews
$ python -m venv venv
my_pc  MINGW64 ~/OneDrive/Documents/Trading/interviews
$ source venv/bin/activate
(venv) 
my_pc  MINGW64 ~/OneDrive/Documents/Trading/interviews
$ which python
/c/Users/my_pc/OneDrive/Documents/Trading/interviews/venv/bin/python
(venv) 
my_pc  MINGW64 ~/OneDrive/Documents/Trading/interviews
$ pip --version
pip 22.3.1 from C:/Users/my_pc/OneDrive/Documents/Trading/interviews/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip (python 3.10)
(venv) 
my_pc MINGW64 ~/OneDrive/Documents/Trading/interviews
$ pip install numpy
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None))': /simple/numpy/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None))': /simple/numpy/
Collecting numpy
  Using cached numpy-1.24.2.tar.gz (10.9 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [40 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Users\my_pc\OneDrive\Documents\Trading\interviews\venv\lib\python3.10\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "C:\Users\my_pc\OneDrive\Documents\Trading\interviews\venv\lib\python3.10\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
        File "C:\Users\my_pc\OneDrive\Documents\Trading\interviews\venv\lib\python3.10\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 112, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          backend = _build_backend()
        File "C:\Users\my_pc\OneDrive\Documents\Trading\interviews\venv\lib\python3.10\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 77, in _build_backend
          obj = import_module(mod_path)
        File "C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
          return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 992, in _find_and_load_unlocked
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 887, in exec_module
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
        File "C:/Users/my_pc/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-build-env-ocqvaqmi/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 242, in <module>    
          monkey.patch_all()
        File "C:/Users/my_pc/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-build-env-ocqvaqmi/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/monkey.py", line 99, in patch_all      
          patch_for_msvc_specialized_compiler()
        File "C:/Users/my_pc/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-build-env-ocqvaqmi/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/monkey.py", line 162, in patch_for_msvc_specialized_compiler
          patch_func(*msvc9('find_vcvarsall'))
        File "C:/Users/my_pc/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-build-env-ocqvaqmi/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/monkey.py", line 149, in patch_params  
          mod = import_module(mod_name)
        File "C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
          return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 887, in exec_module
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
        File "C:/Users/ndamb/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-build-env-ocqvaqmi/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/msvc9compiler.py", line 295, in <module>
          raise DistutilsPlatformError("VC %0.1f is not supported by this module" % VERSION)
      distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError: VC 6.0 is not supported by this module
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

I tried using `python3 -m pip install numpy`, `python -m pip install numpy`, etc. but couldn't get past this error. I also can't run it without the venv for the reasons that I mentioned above.

Comment: py -m pip install numpy